# OpenGL ES 2.0 Ortho Coordinates

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to move from OpenGL C++ to OpenGL ES 2.0, and I'm not exactly sure how the matrices work anymore. 
Previously, I used glOrtho to set up a grid in projectionView, with the origin in the center, something like this: (the y ratio is usually always 1)

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-ASPECT_RATIO_X, ASPECT_RATIO_X, -ASPECT_RATIO_Y,
ASPECT_RATIO_Y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Moving into android I attempted to do the same thing, but it seems the coordinate plane is not set correctly. The coordinate plane seems to range from -1 to 1 on both axes. The x-axis should be -ratio to ratio. Here's what I attempted to do inside the onSurfaceChanged() function:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mtrxProjection, 0);
Matrix.setIdentityM(mtrxView, 0);
Matrix.setIdentityM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);

Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 50);

Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
```

onDrawFrame, I clear,reset the matrix, and draw entities:

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Matrix.setIdentityM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
//draw entities here
```

Here's how I setup matrices for every Entity (built for every render call):

```
float[] scaleMatrix = new float[16];
scaleMatrix[0] = scale.x;
scaleMatrix[5] = scale.y;
scaleMatrix[10] = scale.z;
scaleMatrix[15] = 1;

translateMatrix[12] = position.x;
translateMatrix[13] = position.y;
translateMatrix[14] = position.z;

float[] rotationXMatrix = new float[16];
float[] rotationYMatrix = new float[16];
float[] rotationZMatrix = new float[16];

Matrix.setIdentityM(matrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, scaleMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);
Matrix.setRotateM(rotationXMatrix, 0, rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
Matrix.setRotateM(rotationYMatrix, 0, rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
Matrix.setRotateM(rotationZMatrix, 0, rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, rotationXMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, rotationYMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, rotationZMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, translateMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);

Matrix.multiplyMM(GLRenderer.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, GLRenderer.mtrxView, 0, matrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(GLRenderer.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, GLRenderer.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, GLRenderer.mtrxProjection, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The order of operations of matrix multiplication messed it up, on the last line:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(GLRenderer.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0,
GLRenderer.mtrxProjection, 0, GLRenderer.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);
```

Comment: The main problem in the code you posted is that you never use the matrices you calculate. If this makes a change, I figure you must be applying them somewhere in code you did not show?

Comment: It's applied through the shaders:
`int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");`
`GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, GLRenderer.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);`